# Updated my android APK in android studio , should I sign and generate again or just build and release?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console

Hello I have signed and generated my app-release.aab and uploaded to playstore now I am asked to add a code to the XML file.which I have done now Should I generate and sign it again or just build and release?

I have not tried anything yet . Avoiding complications. Am still very new to flutter

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.